# Kendo UI Grid: is it possible to have more than one grid on the page without element ID collisions?

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

Is it possible to have more than one Kendo UI grid on the page?
EDIT: The grids have to be visible simultaneously.

With some jQuery grids I've tried in the past, it was not possible to have more than one grid instance on a page because the IDs assigned by the grid to its child DOM elements were not prefixed with the grid id; having more than one grid on the page would create two or more DOM elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, I have implemented this in my project with none of the issues you mention. I had 3 grids in one page.

UPDATE: the base widget element has whatever ID you assign it by yourself. As for the child elements, they don't use IDs, rather they use data- attributes. I havent' seen a single ID in the whole grid I have. Here is an example of how a table header looks like in one of my grids:

```
<thead class="k-reorderable" data-role="reorderable">
<tr>
<th class="k-header" data-title="Service name" data-field="Name" role="columnheader" data-role="sortable">
<a class="k-link" href="#">Service name</a>
</th>
<th class="k-header" data-title="Lasting time" data-field="LastingTime" role="columnheader" data-role="sortable">
<a class="k-link" href="#">Lasting time</a>
</th>
<th class="k-header" data-title="Price" data-field="Price" role="columnheader" data-role="sortable">
<a class="k-link" href="#">Price</a>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

The data rows use UIDs to distinguish themselves, here is anotoher example:

```
<tr class="k-alt" role="row" data-uid="f2cd4f59-8492-4616-8fc6-5d65ec466437">
<td role="gridcell">Test</td>
<td role="gridcell">01:00:00</td>
<td role="gridcell">500</td>
</tr>
```

I suggest you just check out the examples on http://demos.kendoui.com/ and inspect the html the grid generates for more details.

I don't think you should really access specific child elements directly through the DOM. Sticking to the widget API is what i suggest, and thats why its there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A more elaborate analysis of what is wrong in the OP case would be much more helpful.

Comment: @Serge Belov: Those other grids assumed only one instance per page and did not prefix the grid ID to their child element IDs, e.g. not StockGrid-Header1 but rather Header1 (a hypothetical example). With two grids on a page, both contained an element whose "unique" ID was 'Header1'. Thus, `getElementById('Header1')` was not possible; furthermore, as these identically named elements were not always nested in the same location within the structure, depending on what features were enabled, it was almost impossible to create generic functions to address the elements using other selectors.

Comment: @Dennis Puzak: Thank you for the reply. I will be happy to give you the green Check Mark, accepting your answer; but before I formally accept it, could you please describe the Kendo UI ID-naming conventions? I am being a "stickler" here, asking for a very specific answer, only because with those other grids, the ID-collision bugs were subtle; multiple grids per page seemed to work OK and I did not immediately detect any behavior anomalies. `Are the Kendo UI ID-naming conventions designed to prevent ID collisions with multiple object instances?` Thanks again.

Comment: I appologize to everyone if my answer was not specific enough. I am new to stack overflow and just shoot what came to my mind first with the thought of being helpful in mind :) I will update my answer.

Comment: @Dennis Puzak: thanks for the additional comment `I haven't seen a single ID in the ... grid`.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, yeah!  We have pages that literally have hundreds.

But to be more precise we load most of them on-demand.  For that start by looking at the Kendo TabControl it makes that really easy.

This is "one" of many ways to load them in via partials with dynamically assigned names.  We even have one case where we use GUIDs.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model PeopleViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PersonQualificationModel>()
    .Name("QualificationEditGrid_" + Model.PersonId)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "clear: both;" })
...
```

If you allow editing.  You will have collisions if you try to edit in multiple grids at the same time if they have the same type of data.  In this example if you tried to edit two qualifications in different grids at the same time, it would cause a problem.

EDIT:

If you know you are going to have N-number of grids with identical data types, you could make an N-number of models and name their properties uniquely and use each different model on each grid.  This would fix your collision issue, to a point.  This may not even be what you are asking.

Comment: thanks for the help. The grids need to be visible at the same time, so Tab control and load-on-demand is not an option. e.g. (1) Top 10 Stocks and their data; (2) Top Ten Real Estate Projects; (3) Top 10 Gambling Casinos -- each grid having a different schema.

Comment: Clearly you don't understand what I am explaining.  My bad.